# remote server headers dont match AngularJS reported size of $http.get(...) data

Tags: angularjs, facebook

Having a strange problem.  I'm downloading a user Pic from the facebook API using the URL supplied from facebook's /me graph api and a simple $http.get(...) call.  This is being performed client side, in an AngularJS app (v1.4.4 of AngularJS)

```
Facebook.api("/v2.3/me",{fields: 'id,name,first_name,picture.width(160).height(160)'},
     function (response) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    console.log(response.picture.data.url);
                    $scope.fbuser.picture = response.picture.data.url;
                    $http.get($scope.fbuser.picture)
                    .success(function (picdata, status, headers, config) {
                            console.log("retrieved "+picdata.length+" bytes");
   ..etc..
```

the $http.get(...) returns a picdata string that is shorter than the server says it is. To rule out something Facebookesque, I changed to use a file on my server... and see the same result with the same picture.  According to the headers I see in the browser, the length the image should be 5886 bytes...

**Accept-Ranges:bytes

Cache-Control:max-age=84600, public, no-transform

Content-Length:5886

Content-Type:image/jpeg

Date:Sun, 27 Sep 2015 04:06:10 GMT

ETag:"c01bf-16fe-520b2957e00e9"

Expires:Mon, 28 Sep 2015 03:36:10 GMT

Last-Modified:Sun, 27 Sep 2015 03:57:47 GMT

Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)**

However, when I log the picdata.length I'm getting 5727 bytes

if I loop through the picdata string, I find that some of the **picdata.charCodeAt(i)** chars have values > 255... which would lead me to believe this string is not a simple ASCII string... but shouldnt the $http.get just return a byte array?

I know the URI retrieved is ok - if I use the URI in a browser, the browser is able to load the picture fine.

If I try and build an image out of the data obtained from the URI (build a blob and use that as an image) I get a broken image.

The fact that I'm seeing this from Facebook **and** a local file suggests that clearly I'm missing something here....

Comment: doesn't make sense to use ajax for this. Create an image element using the `src` and convert from there

Comment: @charlietfl - that's so simple I overlooked it... 

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = response.picture.data.url;

should do the trick.. I'll have to try it when I get home... **thank you**.

But it doesnt explain the behaviour I'm seeing above....I'd really like to understand that before it bites me somewhere else...

Comment: ajax isn't intended for that content type is all i can suggest. If send from server code would be as blob